# Percentage of Mac users vs PC

Tags: windows, macos, mac

I saw this image on Wikipedia and was wondering if a similar chart existed for Mac vs. PC?

[image: Usage share of web browsers: February 2010]

Comment: Just for nitpickyness: Macs are PCs too and were even marketed as such in the G4/G5 era. Technically there are no differences :-)

Comment: Technically, sure, but Apple tries very hard to make sure their software is only compatible with their hardware.

Comment: @Nick - That's because Apple's a jerk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StatCounter hosts some stats that they collect through their stats package: [StatCounter GlobalStats](http://gs.statcounter.com/). The graph is available as a bar or line graph for trends over time but not a pie graph.

Interestingly, Mac OS X is about 4% worldwide according to their stats, but it's ~9% and ~10% in Canada and the States respectively.

Comment: PCs absolutely dominate in Asia, Africa, and most parts of Europe because the hardware is dirt cheap and Windows is widely pirated. Buying legal copies of Windows is almost unheard of.

Comment: Since (almost) every new computer includes a license of Windows, I'd say the majority of used Windows installations comes from that angle. Sure, nobody ever buys Windows separately, but I don't think that equals having no legal license.

Comment: @Johannes - Yes, but even amongst more techy people who generally build their computers from scratch (and hence don't receive OEM windows), buying windows is still unheard of.

Comment: If no-one would buy Windows in those regions, why would Microsoft still be investing money in localisations then?

Comment: @Arian - Corporations buy windows, and OEMs who resell there bundle windows, which they buy. It's just uncommon on a personal level.

Comment: I realize this post is a few years old (just days over 5 years old, in fact,) but thanks! I'll keep this bookmarked. It looks like OS X has climbed up to be over 10% worldwide over the years (and over 15% in North America). If it continues at that exponential rate (doubling ever 5 years), it'll take 50% of the worldwide market in ~2027.

Answer (score 4):

Per Net Applications Market Share application:

- Windows 93.06% (93.04%)
- Mac 4.87% (4.86%)
- Linux 0.94% (1.05%)
- iPhone 0.33% (0.30%)
- JavaME 0.31% (0.29%)
- Symbian 0.14% (0.14%)
- Windows Mobile (0.04%)
- All others combined (0.10%)

[image: Pie chart illustrating operating system marketshare]

Comment: Citation needed.

Comment: You should have linked that to this: http://xkcd.com/285/

Comment: "Per Net Applications Market Share application:" What more citation could I have provided?

Comment: how about a source? ;p

Comment: @Lucas McCoy, +1 you gotta love that cartoon... I feel this one is appropriate here to: http://xkcd.com/323/

Comment: Citation without a link is sufficient here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2010/03/mac-os-x-north-american-installed-base-almost-11.ars), North America have almost %11 of the market. I guess you will get different numbers for each region.